# emailSimple REST action

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to invoke an action through the Force.com REST API but I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax of the request body.  I looked for an example of this command but didn't see any.  Here is what I've got in a REST client:

POST 'https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/actions/standard/emailSimple'
Content-Type: application/json
'Authorization : Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
{"emailAddresses":"XXXXX@abc.com","emailSubject":"TESTING","emailBody":"message body"}

I get the following error:
"Unrecognized field "emailAddresses" at [line:1, column:20]"

Comment: What does you emailSimple action do? It is telling you that emailAddresses is not a valid field. I could not find a standard SF action named emailSimple

Comment: emailSimple sends an email where you specify the subject, body, and recipients.  It's in v32 of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
{"inputs" : [{"emailAddresses":"XXXXX@abc.com","emailSubject":"TESTING","emailBody":"message body"}]}
```